# can't get SSHFS Win Manager to connect to an SSH/SFTP server

Tags: windows, sftp

I have set up some virtual machines / VPSs, hosted by digitalocean, ("digital ocean droplets"). I can SSH to them which means I can do SFTP.

Connecting with an SFTP client is all well and good, like FileZilla Client(or WinSCP client, which supports SFTP), but I want to map the drives of some of the virtual machines, to drive letters on my windows computer.

I did a google about that and it came up with SSHFS Win Manager for Windows. https://sftptogo.com/blog/how-to-map-sftp-as-a-windows-10-drive/  (though i'm on Windows 7). I don't know if maybe it's not a program many people use, which might explain a few things.

I can't get SSHFS for Windows, to connect to an SSH/SFTP server.

[image]

I can SSH to it from cygwin

(the file "bleh", is just a copy of the private key, id_rsa)

```
$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/bleh user@164....
```

FileZilla is fine with it too.

But SSHFS Win Manager can't connect to it. The settings seem all fine.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to use https://github.com/winfsp/sshfs-win it with another GUI, or without GUI?

**added by barlop**

https://github.com/winfsp/sshfs-win/blob/master/README.md

(have WinFSP installed, which is the foundation for sshfs-win).

put ssh private key(id_rsa file), in the directory it wants me to %userprofile%.ssh  I made the directory and put the file in there.

then.

> ```
> C:\Users\User>net use V: \\sshfs.k\bob@164....
> The command completed successfully.
> ```

(no need for the sshfs win manager GUI).

Comment: ah I didn't realise its base was a command line thing, i'll give that a try.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like that program isn't getting much use,

https://github.com/evsar3/sshfs-win-manager/tree/v1.3.1   people posting issues with SFTP Win Manager,  that are quite serious and no responses.

There is a program called Expandrive that works, is set up very quickly, is versatile as it supports many services besides SFTP, though it's not free

[Is it possible to map as a network drive, a server that I SFTP to?](https://superuser.com/questions/1723415/is-it-possible-to-map-as-a-network-drive-a-server-that-i-sftp-to/1723416#1723416)